# Merge / combine 2 dataframes in Python replacing rows in dataframe 1 with duplicates values in 2 columns from dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes that I would like to combine into 1. The second of the 2 dataframes, I would like to overwrite rows with identical 'x' and 'y' values. I would also like to overwrite these rows with the 'population' value from dataframe 2.

I have tried the following, but it does not seem to be providing what I need.

```
df_out = df2.merge(same, 
                   on=['x', 'y'], 
                   how='outer', indicator=True)

df_out['population'] = np.where(df_out['_merge'] == 'both',
                         df_out['population_x'],
                         df_out
                           .population_y
                           .add(df_out.population_x, fill_value=0))\
                       .astype(int)

df_out[['population', 'x', 'y']]
```

[Image showing dataframe 1 and dataframe 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM97g.jpg)

df_out after each step:

[image: Value of df_out after each step]

Apologies if I have not included the required info or given the correct format, this is the first question I have posted. Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Can you show the value of `df_out` after each step?

Comment: Hi Nicolas78, thanks a lot for getting back to me! I have added an image to the question.

Comment: ok cool. as a general comment - you could also paste the results as text into your example. also, the last output can go as df_out didn't change.

Comment: now more to the point, can you point at an example where it's going wrong? it's hard to see here because population_y is either NaN or equal to population_x

I think if you had one example of "here's what I get, and here's what I would expect", that might help (off now though)